# Getting values from provisioner (null_resource) block

Tags: azure, curl, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hello I have been having difficulties trying to get the hostnames from virtual machines. I want to use the hostnames to run some curl command

Here is the terraform code

```
data "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" "virtual_machine" {
  name                = var.vm_name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
}


resource "null_resource" "get_hostname" {
  count = var.instances
  provisioner "remote-exec" {


    connection {
      type     = "ssh"
      user     = var.vm_username
      password = var.vm_password
      host     = data.azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.virtual_machine.instances[count.index].private_ip_address
    }
    inline = [
      "hostname -a",
    ]
  }

}
```

The above command works very fine. it logs into the server

I want to use the hostnames in the curl command below code

```
resource "null_resource" "add_dns_record" {
   count = var.instances

   provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = <<EOT
       curl -X POST "_name": "${hostnames}$
     EOT
 }
```

How do I get the `hostnames` from the `null_resource` block and pass it to the curl command?

Comment: What you could do is write the names of the hosts into a text file, and then use the text file in the next `null_resource`. As a side note, `null_resource` will be deprecated and you should probably move to the `terraform_data` resource going forward.

Comment: Hi @MarkoE. Can you guide me on how I will write the hosts into a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we could technically cut down a tree with a hammer, but is that the right tool for the job?

Terraform really shines with Infrastructure, but as soon as you start mixing `remote-exec` with `local-exec` or anything that feels like a hack, you should start asking yourself if you need a second tool like Ansible, Chef, Puppet or some other.

---

##### Documentation for `virtual_machine_scale_set`

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/virtual_machine_scale_set

We can see in the attributes reference the instances block:

> `instances` exports the following:
>
> `computer_name` - The Hostname of this Virtual Machine.

I'm assuming that will provide the correct hostnames, so you could do:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" "x" {
  name                = var.vm_name
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
}

resource "null_resource" "add_dns_record" {
   count = length(data.azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.x.instances)

   provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = <<EOT
       curl -X POST "_name": ${data.azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.x.instances[count.index].computer_name}
     EOT
 }
```

---

##### Assuming that `hostnames` is a Terraform variable somewhere in your code ...

You have a parsing problem here:
`curl -X POST "_name": "${hostnames}$`

that should be:
`curl -X POST "_name": "${hostnames}"`

---

I was looking at some of the stuff I've done in the past and here is a good example:

```
resource "random_string" "key" {
  length  = 32
  special = false
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command     = <<EOT
        echo "${random_string.key.result}"
    EOT
  }
}
```

---

##### If you want to get that `hostnames` in the Bash code ...

I strongly recommend you to read:
https://linuxhint.com/bash_command_output_variable/

You can use a variable to get the output of a command, something like:

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command     = <<EOT
        hostnames=$(your_command_here)
        curl -X POST "_name": $hostnames
    EOT
  }
}
```

Comment: The command `hostname -a` gets the hostnames of the machine. How do I pass it to the curl command?

Comment: @doctore using the bash -c example above, you can do `curl -d $(hostname -a) http://url`

Comment: @doctore Take a look at my edits I added a couple more options

Comment: @HelderSepulveda What you said is correct. ‘computer_name’ does not export any value because there’s no API to fetch the value.

Comment: @doctore what do you mean there is no API to fetch the value? ... as far as I can see in the Azure Terrraform provider the code is there: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/internal/services/compute/virtual_machine_scale_set_data_source.go#L291

Comment: If the Azure Terrraform provider is not behaving as expected you should report it as a bug: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=Bug_Report.yml

Comment: @HelderSepulveda when I run the code, it doesn't get the `computer_name`

Comment: @doctore that feels like a bug, you should report it

Comment: @HelderSepulveda how do I report it. I have screenshots and the complete code